# Regular Expression help: Comma separated list

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to (in php)

> 1. Verify that the contents of a textarea are valid
> 2. Separate them into the tokens for processing

In order to be considered valid, it needs to be a string containing only numbers and letters that form a "code" that is anywhere from 3-6 in length, and the comma used to separate them. I've broken this down into something like this:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]{3,6},
```

I'm having trouble finishing it though. I want them to be able to separate with either a comma, or a space and comma space, comma space, etc. I only want there to be a comma if there is a following valid token.

For example, the input string:

> abe 123, PlE43,54drt , r2344

Should be separated into the following tokens:

> 'abe 123' and 'PlE43' and '54drt' and 'r2344'

How can I fix my regex to fit the conditions? (right now I'm having trouble making the comma optional, but if it is there I expect another valid token, as well as using comma and any combination of space before or after as a valid separator)

Comment: Is this **one** token? `abe 123`

Comment: @Jon yes this "code" is one token

Comment: so a token should rather be defined as `[A-Za-z0-9 ]{3,6}`. Notice the space.

Comment: @KarlsFriend: I believe that's not right, because in this case `abe 123` is not a valid token (7 chars if you count the space). Relaxing the grammar to tolerate spaces makes it quite trickier.

Comment: The `'abe 123'` token should be invalid because it has seven characters. Yes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you want to collapse all spaces (i.e., both spaces inside a token and spaces between tokens/next to commas should be ignored), you can do it much more simply with some preprocessing.

```
$input = 'abe 123, PlE43,54drt , r2344';
$input = str_replace(' ', '', $input); // strip all spaces
$tokens = explode(',', $input);
foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,6}$/', $token)) {
        // error
    }
}
```

This code will also report an error if you have two consecutive commas, or if you end the input string with a comma, because that would generate an empty element in `$tokens` which does not validate by the 3-to-6 alphanumeric rule.

[See it in action](http://ideone.com/Ss6FE).

**Update**: to preserve the spaces *inside* tokens, a slight modification would be required:

```
$input = 'abe 123, PlE43,54drt , r2344';
$tokens = explode(',', $input);
foreach ($tokens as &$token) {
    $token = trim($token);
    if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,6}$/', str_replace(' ', '', $token))) {
        // error
    }
}
```

Be careful with this though, as it thinks that

```
 a         b                       42
```

is one valid token.

Comment: Note that this will also strip the space out of `abe 123` in your example. The asker may want to preserve that.

Comment: @Justin Morgan I would like to preserve that space. Even though @Jon does mention that in his answer, is there a way to modify it to keep that space?

Comment: @Diego: See the update, but also keep in mind that the 3-to-6 rule might interact strangely with the "spaces are fine" rule.

Comment: @Diego - You could do it the way he does here, or you could use regex for the whole thing like in my own answer. It's up to you. Personally I like a regex one-liner for this, but it's personal preference. He's right about the 3/6 rule, I don't know if you want to include spaces in the count or not.

Comment: @JustinMorgan: I might have preferred a regex as well, but did you try validating `123 abc` (7 chars in total) with a regex? It has to match. It would be difficult to impossible to get this right with a regex.

Comment: @JustinMorgan: OK, now you just have to get *all* the matches out of that regex :) This is precisely the reason why I wanted to avoid getting bogged down in regexes in the first place.

Comment: True. I think I'd go your way if I didn't want to include spaces in the count, and with the one-liner otherwise. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Assumed requirements:

- Each token consists of letters, digits and spaces but must contain at least one letter and at least one number.
- The total length of the token is from 3-6 characters, which includes any internal spaces.
- It is assumed that the 3-6 character length restriction includes any spaces. (Thus: "abe 123", which has 7 characters, would be invalid.)
- Given that the commas separating the tokens may have optional whitespace (which is to be ignored), it is implied that tokens may never begin or end with a space (but may contain embedded spaces).

Here is a tested PHP function which validates a given string and returns an array containing the valid tokens. If the string is invalid, it returns false.

```php
// Return array of valid tokens else false if $text is invalid.
function valid_tokens($text) {
    $re_validate = '/
        # Validate comma separated TEXTAREA "Codes" tokens.
        ^                          # Anchor to start of string.
        \s*+                       # Optional leading whitespace.
        (?:                        # Group comma separated tokens.
          (?=[0-9 ]{0,5}[A-Za-z])  # Must contain at least one letter.
          (?=[A-Za-z ]{0,5}[0-9])  # Must contain at least one digit.
          [A-Za-z0-9]              # First char is number or digit.
          [A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,4}        # Middle chars numbers, digits or spaces.
          [A-Za-z0-9]              # Last char is number or digit.
          \s*                      # Optional whitespace following token.
          (?:                      # Group for "end of token" options.
            ,\s*                   # Either a comma, optional whitespace,
          | $                      # or end of string.
          )                        # End "end of token" options group.
        )++                        # One or more tokens required.
        $                          # Anchor to end of string.
        /x';
    // Check validity of comma separated tokens (tokens may contain spaces).
    if (preg_match($re_validate, $text)) {
        $re_match = '/
            # Match next comma separated token. Capture in group $1.
            \s*+                 # Discard optional leading whitespace.
            (                    # $1: Comma separated token.
              [A-Za-z0-9]        # First char is number or digit.
              [A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,4}  # Middle chars numbers, digits or spaces.
              [A-Za-z0-9]        # Last char is number or digit.
            )                    # End $1: Comma separated token.
            \s* ,?               # Discard comma separator if its there.
            /x';
        preg_match_all($re_match, $text, $matches);
        return $matches[1]; // Return array of valid tokens.
    }
    // Case 2: TEXTAREA does not contain valid tokens. Return false.
    else return FALSE;
}
```

This script uses two main regexes; one to validate the whole string of comma separated tokens and another to extract each of the values.

**Edit:** My original reading of the question made it more complex than it needed to be. This simplified version allows only comma separated tokens.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]{3,6}((\s*\,\s*)[A-Za-z0-9]{3,6}|(\s)*)
```

Answer (score 0):

This regexp might do the job.

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]{3,6} *, *)*[A-Za-z0-9]{3,6}$
```

It first looks for any number of tokens, followed by a sperator. Then it expects a single token. 
In this case any number of spaces is allowed before and after the comma. You might want to tweak that.

Your example will not match, because it contains a space in the first token(without a comma). If you want it to pass, you should add the space to the valid character token-list.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the following:

```
/^(?:([A-Za-z0-9\s]{3,6})\s*(?:,\s*|$))*/
```

That will put each textarea's contents into capture group 1. Note that I've modified your `[A-Za-z0-9]` to `[A-Za-z0-9\s]`, which will allow the whitespace in your `abe 123` example. This will also trim whitespace around the comma.

Note that this won't trim whitespace from the very beginning and end of the string. I suggest you trim those too, for consistency. The regex to do that would be:

```
/^(?:\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]{3,6})\s*(?:,|$))*/
```

One more update: If you want to ignore spaces in your 3-6 character count, you can do this:

```
/^(?:((?:\s*[A-Za-z0-9]\s*){3,6})(?:,|$))*/
```